# Chef error installing mysql using 'database::mysql' recipe

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, cookbook

Following [Getting Started Writing Chef Cookbooks the Berkshelf Way](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/16/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way/) tutorial from [misheska blog](http://misheska.com). But specifically in [Part 2 Mysql and Create database](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/23/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way-part2/).

when I execute

```
$ vagrant up
```

or

```
$ vagrant provision
```

I get the following error in console output:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'opscode-ubuntu-12.04'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[Berkshelf] This version of the Berkshelf plugin has not been fully tested on this version of Vagrant.
[Berkshelf] You should check for a newer version of vagrant-berkshelf.
[Berkshelf] If you encounter any errors with this version, please report them at https://github.com/RiotGames/vagrant-berkshelf/issues
[Berkshelf] You can also join the discussion in #berkshelf on Freenode.
[Berkshelf] Updating Vagrant's berkshelf: '/home/montells/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140117-2071-x216zp-default'
[Berkshelf] Using myface (0.1.0)
[Berkshelf] Using mysql (4.0.18)
[Berkshelf] Using openssl (1.1.0)
[Berkshelf] Using build-essential (1.4.2)
[Berkshelf] Using apache2 (1.8.14)
[Berkshelf] Using database (1.6.0)
[Berkshelf] Using postgresql (3.3.4)
[Berkshelf] Using apt (2.3.4)
[Berkshelf] Using aws (1.0.0)
[Berkshelf] Using xfs (1.1.0)
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
[default] Machine booted and ready!
[default] Setting hostname...
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
[default] Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[2014-01-17T14:42:52+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-01-17T14:42:52+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.8.2 ***
[2014-01-17T14:42:52+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1327
[2014-01-17T14:42:55+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[myface::default]"] from JSON
[2014-01-17T14:42:55+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[myface::default]]
[2014-01-17T14:42:55+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [myface::default]
[2014-01-17T14:42:55+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for ubuntu
[2014-01-17T14:42:55+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-01-17T14:42:55+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-01-17T14:42:56+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for directory[/var/lib/mysql] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-01-17T14:42:56+00:00] WARN: Previous directory[/var/lib/mysql]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/_server_debian.rb:34:in `block in from_file'
[2014-01-17T14:42:56+00:00] WARN: Current  directory[/var/lib/mysql]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/_server_debian.rb:70:in `from_file'
[2014-01-17T14:43:06+00:00] INFO: execute[apt-get-update-build-essentials] ran successfully
[2014-01-17T14:45:33+00:00] WARN:  failed to find gem mysql (>= 0) from [http://rubygems.org/]
[2014-01-17T14:45:33+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-01-17T14:45:33+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-01-17T14:45:33+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-01-17T14:45:33+00:00] ERROR: chef_gem[mysql] (mysql::ruby line 47) had an error: ArgumentError: Illformed requirement [""]

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'chef_gem[mysql]'
================================================================================


ArgumentError
-------------
Illformed requirement [""]


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb:47:in `from_file'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/database/recipes/mysql.rb:20:in `from_file'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/database.rb:11:in `from_file'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/default.rb:10:in `from_file'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb

 47: chef_gem 'mysql'



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb:47:in `from_file'

chef_gem("mysql") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
  action :install
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  package_name "mysql"
  cookbook_name :mysql
  recipe_name "ruby"
end




================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================


ArgumentError
-------------
chef_gem[mysql] (mysql::ruby line 47) had an error: ArgumentError: Illformed requirement [""]


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb:47:in `from_file'
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/database/recipes/mysql.rb:20:in `from_file'
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/database.rb:11:in `from_file'
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/myface/recipes/default.rb:10:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/ruby.rb:

 40:    end
 41:  end
 42:  
 43:  node['mysql']['client']['packages'].each do |name|
 44:    resources("package[#{name}]").run_action(:install)
 45:  end
 46:  
 47>> chef_gem 'mysql'
 48:  


[2014-01-17T14:42:52+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-01-17T14:45:33+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

this is my *myface/attributes/default.rb*

```ruby
default['myface']['user'] = 'myface'
default['myface']['group'] = 'myface'
default['myface']['name'] = 'myface'
default['myface']['config'] = 'myface.conf'
default['myface']['document_root'] = '/srv/apache/myface'

#**************** Database attr *********************************************
default['myface']['database']['host'] = 'localhost'
default['myface']['database']['username'] = 'root'
default['myface']['database']['password'] = node['mysql']['server_root_password']
default['myface']['database']['dbname'] = 'myface'
```

*myface/recipes/database.rb*

```ruby
include_recipe 'mysql::server'
include_recipe 'database::mysql'

mysql_database node['myface']['database']['dbname'] do
  connection(
    :host => node['myface']['database']['host'],
    :username => node['myface']['database']['username'],
    :password => node['myface']['database']['password']
  )
  action :create
end
```

*myface/recipes/default.rb*

```ruby
include_recipe 'myface::database'
include_recipe 'myface::webserver'
```

Somebody knows what happen? 
NOTE: Part 1 [Install Apache2](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/16/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way/) works correctly.
Interesting details: I use my own local gem server **geminabox**
I can give more details if someone have ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the debugging output, your gem server does not include the MySQL gem.